# Equation for effects of the density on time dilation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, time-dilation

The higher the density of an object is the more it will cause distortion on  space and time.

I want to know the equation that links density to time dilation.

I found the Lorentz equations that link speed with time dilation but I cannot find the equations that does it for gravity...

Any help?

Comment: There isn't one.

Comment: Is it because there is just not one yet or am I wrong in my understanding of the General relativity?

Comment: The problem is _much_ harder to solve than you seem to think, so the latter.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solutions_of_the_Einstein_field_equations#Solving_the_equations

Comment: didn't know it was that hard before your first message nut that was what I implied by "there is just not one yet".

doesn't help my issue but it does help for my general knowledge... thank you

Comment: Unless you _really_ mean mass rather than density, in which case read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift

Comment: nope I needed density as I wanted to take in consideration the volume as well.

Comment: OK in that case my first comment stands.

Answer (score 2):

The density determines the curvature by the [Einstein field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations):
$$R_{\mu \nu} - \tfrac{1}{2} R g_{\mu \nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu \nu} = \kappa T_{\mu \nu},$$
where $R_{\mu \nu}$ is a curvature tensor built up from derivatives of $g_{\mu \nu}$ and $R=R^\mu{}_\mu.$

The density however doesn't directly determine the gravitational time dilation. That can instead be determined from an actual solution
$$
g_{\mu \nu} = \phi(x) \, dt^2 - (\text{spatial distance})
$$
by taking ratios of $\phi(x)$ for different positions.

Comment: Hoped to avoid those as they are the super complicated part of Einstein GTR... I guess I won't be abble to do what I wanted by myself :(

But thanks a lot.